# Polynomial fit using curve_fit()

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I've been attempting to get the best polynomial fit possible for my data points using curve_fit() yet my code is giving the following error. Could somebody assist me comprehend where the glitch lies. Many thanks in advance.

TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_xor' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.interpolate import *   
def func(x, a, b, c, d):
    return a*x^3 + b*x^2 + c * x + d

Xdata1 = np.array([10, 20, 30, 60])
Ydata1 = np.array([3, 5, 4, 3.5])

plt.plot(Xdata1, Ydata1, 'bo', label='Raw Data')

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, Xdata1, Ydata1)
a, b, c, d= popt
plt.plot(Xdata1, func(Xdata1, *popt), 'r--', label='fit')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out already `^` is a bit-wise operator, namely the bitwise XOR (exclusive OR) operator.

https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations

In any case since you are trying to fit a regular polynomial, if you don't want to deal with custom functions and arguments specification in the scipy.optimize package, you can also try the `numpy.polyfit` fucntion. You can specify the polynomial degree and get the coefficient right away. 
It uses a least square approach.

In your case would be something like

`numpy.polyfit(Xdata1,Ydata1,3)`

which yields the coefficients of the degreee 3 fitting polynomial

`array([ 0.34166667, -3.55      , 10.25833333, -4.05      ])`

Comment: Many thanks for your prompt reply. I made use of polyfit() just like you pointed out, yet, the issue is its returning broken lines passing through each and every data point with R^2 = 1. I kinda moved away from polyfit() since I'm more looking to obtain a sort of smooth line (curve-like thing) that best describes data (with the finest R squared possible). Am I on the right track to achieve this by appealing to curve_fit() rather than polyfit()?

Comment: If you were able to get ```popt``` from any of the two fitting procedures yes, you are very close to get what you want. You just have to change the part in which you plot the fitted curve. You get a broken line because you are using again ```Xdata1``` for plotting the fitting curve. Instead, you have to use a more dense array spanning a similar range. Given your ```Xdata1``` values i would try something like this: `plt.plot(np.arange(0,70,0.5), func(np.arange(0,70,0.5), *popt), 'r--', label='fit')`. (Please accept the answer if this solves your issue)

Answer (score 4):

You should use `**` rather than `^` which is a bitwise operator